# PowerApps duplicate selection (Dataverse)

Tags: filter, duplicates, powerapps, dataverse

I have a datatable in PowerApps in which I only want to show rows with duplicate values.

In that table I have quite a few columns, it's just the 'Title' column that I want to use to show duplicate values. Meaning even if other columns have different values, if three rows have same 'Title' all three should show in the duplicate table.

If I try using lookup then i will have to for each selected record match the other records, this is quite impossible to do with large dataset

Comment: This cannot be achieved using the standard query (`QueryExpression`, fetch XML) capabilities